# how is the code for parsing Json parsing?

Tags: iphone, json, ios5

Hi I have implemented code for parsing the below response as follows but it is not working properly:

```
 NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" My URL"];   
 NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];        
 NSDictionary *resultsDict = [googleResponse valueForKey:  @"eventtitle"];
```

What is the code for parsing the below response? Please give me solution.

```
{
  "AlansHarleyEvents": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "eventtitle": "22nd Annual Pig Roast",
      "eventdate": "April 22nd 8am-5pm"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "eventtitle": "Poker Run",
      "eventdate": "April 28th 8am at Shooters"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "eventtitle": "Kickstands for kids",
      "eventdate": "May 12th 8am-5pm"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "eventtitle": "Ride for the Cure",
      "eventdate": "May28th 8am Free Drinks!"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "eventtitle": "Veterans Ride",
      "eventdate": "June 10th 9am @City Hall"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "eventtitle": "Biker Beach Bash",
      "eventdate": "June 28th 8-5pm @ The Pier"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "eventtitle": "22nd Annual Pig Roast",
      "eventdate": "April 22nd 8am-5pm"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "eventtitle": "Poker Run",
      "eventdate": "April 28th 8am at Shooters Lounge"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "eventtitle": "22nd Annual Pig Roast",
      "eventdate": "April 22nd 8am-5pm"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "eventtitle": "Swamp Run",
      "eventdate": "April 22nd 8am-5pm"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `resultsDict` contains the above JSON response then you can parse it as :

```
NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" My URL"];
NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];
NSDictionary *resultsDict = [googleResponse valueForKey: @"eventtitle"];

NSMutableArray *resultArray = [resultsDict valueForKey:@"AlansHarleyEvents"]; 

for(int i = 0; i<[resultArray count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[resultArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"]) ;
    NSLog(@"%@",[[resultArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"eventtitle"]) ;
    NSLog(@"%@",[[resultArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"eventdate"]) ; 
}
```

Comment: I think that the downvote is caused by the fact that `resultsDict` doesn't has a key/value `AlansHarleyEvents`.

Comment: @maulik: when i used ur code it giving me null value at the point of       NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];

Answer (score 1):

NSJSONSerialization Class is the Native Class for only iOS 5 and above 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

For any iPhone OS version means you can go for JSONKit:
https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Answer (score 1):

Yu can use NSJSONSerialization object with IOS 5

```
   NSDictionnary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resultsDict options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```